# How to bold a cell based on the value?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I bold all cells that contain 1470?

I tried looping

```
Sub bold()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("j259:j291")
    For Each cell In rng
        If rng.Cells = "1470" Then
            rng.Cells.Font.bold = True
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I got the error

> "Type mismatch"

Comment: Use `If cell = "1470" Then` or `If cell = 1470 Then`.  Your using `cell` as a variable to contain a reference to each cell in `rng`.  Also use `cell.Font.bold = True` - `rng.Cells.Font.Bold = True` will change `j259:j291` bold as that's what it references.

Comment: If your goal is to bold font with specific word then you can use `Conditional Formatting.`

Comment: But as @Harun24HR comments - conditional formatting would be better.

Comment: is conditional formatting have effect on excel file size?

Comment: If you are only using vba for this, conditional formatting will allow you to use a workbook without macro-enabled. the main difference will be that the conditional formatting will update the format in real time, while the vba code will need to be called for the change to be applied. Note that your code only apply "Bold", and does not remove it if the value is not 1470 anymore.

Comment: @user10182078, don't forget to accept the answer below if it has answered your question. Click the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**

- Wrong use of Range
- Incorrect way to check the Value of each cel

**Advice:**

- Prefer not to use names that are already predefined in Excel, like `Bold`, `Cell` for variables or Module Name
- Specify a Worksheet Name, Otherwise as currently it will work on the Activesheet

**Try:**

```
Sub bld()

    Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In Range("J259:J291")
            If cel.Value = "1470" Then
                cel.Font.bold = True
            End If
        Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Initial question**

> *"Im looking for fastest way to bold all cell that contains value = "1470" by using vba"*

This might be fast if you want to go with VBA instead of conditional formatting:

```
Sub bold()

Dim Rng As Range
Application.ReplaceFormat.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set Rng = .Range("J259:J291")
   Rng.Cells.Replace What:="1470", Lookat:=xlWhole, Replacement:="1470", SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True
End With

End Sub
```

---

**Secundary question:**

> *"addition to my question, if i want to make bold the entire row how can I possibly do it?"*

In order to get your whole rows (or actually those cells you need) quickly bold you could use:

```
Sub bold()

Dim Rng As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = .Range("A258:J291")
    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="1470"
    Rng.Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(12).Font.bold = True
    Rng.AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```

If you want the whole row bold you could also swap the `Rng.Offset...` line with:

```
Rows("259:291").SpecialCells(12).Font.bold = True
```

Adjust the variable `Rng` to suit your needs.

Comment: addition to my question, if i want to make bold the entire row how can I possibly do it?

Comment: @user10182078, I have edited the answer. See if it works for you.